# I tried to store a few columns in variables and display in table but it gives error

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote query and fetched all the rows now I want to store some of the columns in variables so I could use them in list but it doesn't work.
Here is my php code.

There are 20 rows so there should be 20 rows in table! But I think I am missing some points here

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "Bat";
$password = "IamTheBat";
$database = "SpecsCompare";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->mysqli_connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->mysqli_connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

$query_test = "
SELECT * 
  FROM prices p
     , items i
     , shops s
     , categories c 
 WHERE p.shopid = s.shopid 
   AND i.categoryid = c.categoryid 
   AND p.itemid = i.itemid 
   AND i.categoryid = 1004 
   AND s.shopid = 5005
";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query_test);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);
$name = $row['itemname'];
$price = $row['price'];
$category = $row['categoryname'];
$shop = $row['shopname'];
$manufacturer = = $row['manufacturername'];
$module = $row['modulename'];
$type = $row['typename'];
/*while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['itemname'];
}*/
?>
```

And my table in HTML is as below..

```
   <section class="list">
        <div id="galaxyTable">
          <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
          <thead>
              <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>Price</td>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><td><?php echo $name ?></td></td>
            <td><td><?php echo $price ?></td></td>
            <td><a href="#" class="button">Details</a></td>
        </tr>
          <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
  </table>
  <div id="galaxydetailedTable" class="hidden">
      <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>Category</td>
              <td>Price</td>
              <td>Shop</td>
              <td>Manufacturer</td>
              <td>Module</td>
              <td>Type</td>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $name ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $category ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $price ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $shop ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $manufacturer ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $module ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $type ?></td>   
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: your both code is in one file?

Comment: *"but it gives error"* - Being what *exactly?* You want us to go over your code, test it for you to see what it is? I also don't see proper error checking whatsoever.

Comment: After your line `$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);`, you immediately begin assigning variables $name, $price, etc., but shouldn't that be inside a foreach or something? I mean, `$rows` is your set of results, but you're using `$row` values for assignment, and `$row` doesn't exist yet.

Comment: why you are using both the procedural and oop styles ! stick with one

Comment: $row = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_BOTH); //rename $rows to $row

Comment: Now change your password

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo here you should change this

```
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

into this

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

plus you don't need to assign all of those variables you can simply use `Extract` and it will change assign the key name into a variable with the value

from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

> extract — Import variables into the current symbol table from an array